# Htaccess proxy redirect wordpress error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect domainA.com/folder/ which originates within an older wordpress installtion to domainB.com/folder1/folder2/ which is the link to the page within my new wordpress installation wihtout the url changing.

**I have managed to achieve this** with the .htaccess file inside domainA.com/folder/ which reads:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/folder1/folder2/ [P]
```

The Rewriterule [P] (proxy) flag does what I want and redirects the page without changing the url **but some of the content within my Enfold WP template such as the advanced layer slider and icons fail to load.**

I assume this error is due to some sort of conflict with WP's native htaccess code and I also suspect it has to do with the lines:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I have experimented with adding the first, third and fourth lines to my code but it doesnt work. Does anybody know how I could resolve this issue?

If it makes any difference the wordpress site I want to direct to (domainB.com/folder1/folder2/) is one whithin a Wordpress Network.

For the moment I have changed the [P] flag to [L] flag which redirects and works but changes the url.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the paths of images (the URLs) in advanced layer slider and icons URLs from 
relative to absolute ones (as described in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)), then you can use the `[P]` flag in `.htaccess` again.

Often plugins uses relative paths when outputting content, but this can cause such type of troubles.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip but this did not make any difference I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This following code takes care of permalinks in WorPress and it is recommended to keep the beginning and ending WordPress lines so that WordPress is able to locate it and modify it as needed. You may already have all this and are just not displaying it. I do not know.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

In the other section you probably need to remove the trailing / after folder2 like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/folder1/folder2 [P]
```